# Component-wise sums of permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, permutations, sumsets

Given a set $S$ containing all possible permutations of a vector $v = (1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n)$, find the size of the set $P$, where $P$ is defined as the set of possible component-wise sums obtained by adding $k$ elements of $S$ together. Each element in $P$ is a sum of $k$ vectors from $S$, i.e. $P=\sum_{i=1}^kS$. I'm wondering if there is a nice looking formula for $|P|$ as a function of $n$ and $k$.

Edit: the main reason why I'm considering this is the following. Imagine $n$ players play a game. Each round, they get ranked (without ties). The best player gets $n$ points, the second best $n-1$, etc... and the last one only gets $1$. These points gets added to the scoreboard, which starts at $0$ for each player. I want to know how many possible scoreboards there are after $k$ rounds.

Comment: I was pretty tired, wanted to say component-wise

Comment: I can't find a table in OEIS, but for $k=2$ there's [A175176](https://oeis.org/A175176) with the suggestion that $n=11, k=2$ is unknown.

Comment: As far as I know, counting/describing vectors representable as the sum of two permutations is an open problem, which I have heard Alex Postnikov discuss. You can see him discuss it starting around the 57 minute of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thn16ncB4Js.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references!

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Values for $(n,k)=(11,2)$ and a few larger $n$ are on the way.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev just curious, do you have a nice algorithm to compute those values, or is it just brute force?

Comment: @Talesseed: It's a brute force although a bit optimized. Eg. it starts with computing sequences corresponding to https://oeis.org/A019589 and then sums up their rearrangements. I don't think it's feasible going above $n=14$ this way.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Oh so you get O(n!) complexity that way instead of O(n!^2), nice!